# Expecting JSON/XML data in Webapi

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, webrequest, httpwebresponse

when i request one webapi request, i got error like Expecting JSON/XML data

```
try         
{                
    string oRequest = _xml.UpdateInvereqxml(UserName, Password,OTAhotelid, Invy);                
    string uri = @"service/update";
    System.Net.WebRequest req = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(uri);
    req.Method = "POST";
    req.ContentType = "text/xml";
    System.IO.StreamWriter writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream());
    writer.WriteLine(oRequest);
    writer.Close();
    System.Net.WebResponse rsp = req.GetResponse();
    Stream istrm = rsp.GetResponseStream();
    string StreamReader = new StreamReader(istrm).ReadToEnd();
}
```

Comment: How to solve above error?

Comment: Well maybe the exception is raised by the server, because you send in the wrong Content Type. Or Maybe you missing the correct Accept Header

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using HttpClient to communicate with ASP.NET Web API. The class provides many functions for working with REST service ([example](http://hintdesk.com/how-to-consume-asp-net-web-api-rc-with-httpclient/))

```
public EnumProduct Post(EnumProduct product)
{
HttpResponseMessage reponse = httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync("api/enumproducts/Post", product).Result;
if (reponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
var enumProduct = reponse.Content.ReadAsAsync().Result;
return enumProduct;
}
else
return null;
}
```